# Procedure to train tesseract4.0 on windows

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to extract text from the captured image, to achieve this functionality am using tesseract and i wanted to train tessract with a new font.  Currently am using Windows 10 machine. From the tesseract documentation i understood that training tesseract on windows is not supported (Correct me if my understanding is wrong).

Do we need to move to linux machine to train or is there any way to train it on windows.

do we have any other ways to extract the text  from the image am using python.

Please help me out to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.